# Windows 8 prevent user from uninstalling Modern UI app

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 8, how can I prevent a user from uninstalling a Modern UI app, which can be done really easily from the Start screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This reference](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/disable-uninstall-option-for-windows-8-modern-ui-apps/) provides a simple way:

1. First of all, make sure you are logged in as Administrator
2. Go to the Start Screen and type "gpedit.msc":

   [image]
3. Select Apps from the right sidebar, and then click gpedit.msc in the main window.
4. In "Local Group Policy Editor" go to the following location:

   User Configuration/ Administrative Templates/ Start Menu and Taskbar
5. Then look for the folowing config: "Policy setting named Prevent users from uninstalling applications from Start". Double click it to open the policy settings page:

   [image]
6. Select the option "Enable":

   [image]
7. Run Windows console (cmd.exe from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> hotkey combination)
8. Type

   gpupdate /force
9. After executing it, the "Uninstall" option will disapear and you shouldn't be able to easily unistall it anymore:

   [image]